# Adding an element to a showcase (section element) extends the height of the element and I'm also unable to change the new element's position

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a landing page for a fictitious hat company and trying to add a "Read More" link (p within an a) and it ends up in a fixed position and I'm unable to move it using anything I know, and it also creates an odd height at the bottom of the page. I've been trying to solve this for about 30 minutes now and I don't know what I did wrong. I'm sorry if the question is phrased weirdly, here's my html and css.

https://codepen.io/youssefwael/full/KKzVgxe

The part ruining my page is in line 38;

```html
<a href="#" id="read-more">
<p>Read More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not use 'p' element in 'a' element , or set 'a' element as 'display:inline-block'

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<a>` tag is a inline element.

You have to add

```css
#read-more {
  display: inline-block;
  margin or padding or some code...
}
```

or
`display: block; margin-top: ?` like this

you can see the code here:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/ppwater/pen/KKzVWbB)